# Accessing the @attributes of a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I've got some data that's getting returned from an API and converted into a js object in PHP before being passed back to the browser. One of the values i'm trying to retrieve from this object lives in the objects attributes. Here is what the object structure looks like in JS:
[image]

Currently I can access all properties I need to by calling object.comments for example or object.email.whatever.

What I can't do is access the objects attributes. Ideally I would like to get to the ID via something like object.@attributes.id but this returns an error.

Is it possible to access an objects attributes and if so how should I go about it?

Thanks

Comment: Use the bracket notation to get it. `myObject["@fieldName"]`

Comment: `myObject['@attributes'].get; // -5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access properties using dot notation the property must be a valid identifier. If it's not, you have to use brackets:

```
object['@attributes'].id
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!